# why line 44 is showing list index out of range wheras theres nothing wrong

Tags: python, indexing

I created a beginner project to code or decode a message. The encoder code runs well, but when I try decoding, I get the error:

```py
d2 = d1[-1] + d1[:-1]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Below is my code.

```py
print("STARTED")
inpmsg = input("input your message :\n")
simpmsg = inpmsg.split(" ")

inpEnDe = input("DO YOU WANT TO START ENCODE OR DECODE")
encoderlst = []
if inpEnDe.lower() == "encode":
    r1 = input("input 3 random values: ")
    r2 = input("again input 3 random values: ")
    for word in simpmsg:
        if len(word) > 3:
            e1 = word[1:] + word[0]
            e2 = r1 + e1 + r2
            encoderlst.append(e2)
        else:
            encoderlst.append(word[::-1])
    print(" ".join(encoderlst))
else:
    nwords = []
    for word1 in simpmsg:
        if len(word1) >= 3:
            d1 = word1[3:-3]
            d2 = d1[-1] + d1[:-1]
            dr=d1[-1] + d1[0:-1]
            nwords.append(dr)
        else:
            nwords.append(word1[::-1])
    print(" ".join(nwords))
```

Comment: Clearly there is something wrong - Python doesn't throw exceptions for the fun of it. Have you attempted any debugging? I suggest printing `d1` immediately before this line.
Here's a hint: You are acting on words with three or more letters, then removing the *first and last three letters*, then removing the first and last letters. Can you see the potential problem, here?

Comment: Have you noticed that you only get this error when inputting a message that is shorter than 7 characters? Consider what value `d1` takes on when you provide a word with 6 or fewer characters based `word1[3:-3]`.

Comment: Why would I? You appear to have done nothing to attempt to fix the code yourself, or at the very least understand the error. You've got two comments here, stating exactly the cause of the exception - I suggest you start there.

Answer (score 0):

As per the logic that you're trying to implement for this encoding/decoding algorithm, you need a string of length of at least 10, since you're adding 3 letters to the front(`r1`) and 3 to the end (`r2`), and you're checking for the message to be of at least of 4 in length (`len(word) > 3`).

I updated the code for the same, which is as follows:

```
print("STARTED")
inpmsg = input("Input your message:")
simpmsg = inpmsg.split(" ")

inpEnDe = input("DO YOU WANT TO START ENCODE OR DECODE:")
encoderlst = []

if inpEnDe.lower() == "encode":
    r1 = input("input 3 random values: ")
    r2 = input("again input 3 random values: ")
    for word in simpmsg:
        if len(word) > 3:
            e1 = word[1:] + word[0]
            e2 = r1 + e1 + r2
            encoderlst.append(e2)
        else:
            encoderlst.append(word[::-1])
    
    print(" ".join(encoderlst))
else:
    nwords = []
    for word1 in simpmsg:
        if len(word1) > 9:
            d1 = word1[3:-3]
            d2 = d1[-1] + d1[:-1]
            dr=d1[-1] + d1[0:-1]
            nwords.append(dr)
        else:
            nwords.append(word1[::-1])
    print(" ".join(nwords))
```

And I got the following output.

For encoding

```
STARTED
Input your message: ZERO
DO YOU WANT TO START ENCODE OR DECODE: encode
input 3 random values: 012
again input 3 random values: 789
012EROZ789
```

Now decoding the same encoded message.

```
STARTED
Input your message: 012EROZ789
DO YOU WANT TO START ENCODE OR DECODE: decode
ZERO
```

Comment: Thanks alot but what if len is greater then 9

Comment: It works fine for any string greater than 9 in length. You can run and validate the logic.